pandas: dataframe with multilevel columns shift up the date index to to flatten out
I have data that arrives to me that looks like this:
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
data = [['',           'CCC',     'CCC',     'AAA',   'BBB'  ],
        ['date',       'field1', 'file2',  'field1','field1'],
        ['01/01/2024',  100,      102,       103,     104   ],
        ['01/02/2024',  200,      202,       203,     204   ],
        ['01/03/2024',  300,      302,       303,     304   ]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(df.iloc[:2,1:].values, names=['symbol', None])
df = df.iloc[2:,1:].set_axis(df.iloc[2:,0].rename('date'))
df = df.set_axis(idx, axis=1)
df


i do some processing of the dataframe then i now want to flatten this out a bit to ensure 'date' is on the 2nd row (with the field)..so that if i were to serialize to json or an excel file, it would appear much like the array above.
I am having trouble doing so..I have the below code that has a couple of problems

df.columns.levels[0] seem to return a set like list..with unique values.  so this fails when trying to do the MultiIndex because of different widths of the two arrays
it also returns a sorted list, which means if i were to add it back as an index it would be out of order.

l1_idx = list(df.columns.levels[0])
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)
#reset to flatten out and shift up that 'date' column
df = df.reset_index() 
#now add back the level 0 index - how do we maintain the original order?
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([l1_idx, df.columns])
df = data.set_axis(idx, axis=1)
df

what im hoping for is a dataframe that looks exactly like the array above, but without the 'symbol' label

IIUC, it sounds like you want to take the name of the row-index and insert it as the name of the last level of the column index.
To note, that these types of modifications should only be done at the tail-end of
your analysis- especially if you are intending to not re-ingest these data in pandas
as you will need to undo some of the contortions introduced here.
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
data = [['',           'CCC',     'CCC',     'AAA',   'BBB'  ],
        ['date',       'field1', 'file2',  'field1','field1'],
        ['01/01/2024',  100,      102,       103,     104   ],
        ['01/02/2024',  200,      202,       203,     204   ],
        ['01/03/2024',  300,      302,       303,     304   ]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(df.iloc[:2,1:].values, names=['symbol', None])
df = df.iloc[2:,1:].set_axis(df.iloc[2:,0].rename('date'))
df = df.set_axis(idx, axis=1)
print(df)
# symbol        CCC          AAA    BBB
#            field1 file2 field1 field1
# date
# 01/01/2024    100   102    103    104
# 01/02/2024    200   202    203    204
# 01/03/2024    300   302    303    304

res1 = (
    df.rename_axis([df.columns.names[0], df.index.name], axis=1)
    .rename_axis(None, axis=0)
)

print(res1)
# symbol        CCC          AAA    BBB
# date       field1 file2 field1 field1
# 01/01/2024    100   102    103    104
# 01/02/2024    200   202    203    204
# 01/03/2024    300   302    303    304

## alternatively…
new_cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(df.columns.names[0], df.index.name), *df.columns])
res2 = df.reset_index().set_axis(new_cols, axis=1)
print(res2)
#        symbol    CCC          AAA    BBB
#          date field1 file2 field1 field1
# 0  01/01/2024    100   102    103    104
# 1  01/02/2024    200   202    203    204
# 2  01/03/2024    300   302    303    304


that's right. this is right before getting ready to send it back to client that will load into a spreadsheet without much wrangling necessary.  thx much.  Question so i understand.
when i print out df.columns.names[0] i see "symbol".   i asumed that is the value that is going to get replaced by the index name ('date').  but its not..its the 2nd level instead.  that is a bit confusing to me.

the first solution causes problems when serializing it seems (probably because of a reset_index_..the columns get shifted left...so field1 ends up where the dates are.
the second solutions works almost perfectly. but i would like to also clear out the 'symbol' text. i will see if i can do it..

doing this to get rid of the symbol label for cases where its unwanted seems to work new_cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('', df.index.name), *df.columns], names=['', ''])
thanks for you help.  i do want to understand how pands columns/indexing work better though..some explanation would be greatly appreciated
